readthedocs cannot find requirements.txt
.readthedocs.yaml:
python:
  install:
    - requirements: source/requirements.txt

in docs directory
source
    ├── _static
    ├── _templates
    ├── conf.py
    ├── hardware.rst
    ├── index.rst
    ├── requirements.txt
    └── software.rst

readthedocs build output:
python -m pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir pip setuptools 
python -m pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir sphinx 
python -m pip install --exists-action=w --no-cache-dir -r source/requirements.txt  
ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'source/requirements.txt'

I have tried to check the requirements spelling and cannot find anything wrong.

Are you running these commands from docs directory?

Please include more of your file tree, including the location of .readthedocs.yaml.

I think you should specify the path, something like this may work:
python:
  install:
    - requirements: source/requirements.txt
    - method: pip
      path: .

Ensure that .readthedocs.yml is at the base of your directory
